# Get Names from Values in a select statement + Sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, select

Here is my query

```
Select Gender from Table
```

The result pane shows 
`1`
`1`
`1`
`2`
`2`

But i want the results to be 
`Male`
`Male`
`Male`
`Female`
`Female`

The names `Male` and `Female` wont be present in my database.... I want to just hardcode the names based on values from the select statement....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
Select case WHEN Gender=1 THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' end Gender  from Table
```